# How do I create a new ejabberd user account via http

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-auth

I'm trying to create an new user account on my ejabberd server using http.
I am using the following python script:

```
def create_xmpp_account(username, password):
    ejabberd_api_url = "https://example.com:5443/api/register"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/jason'}
    data = {
        'user': username,
        'host': 'example.com',
        'password': password
    }
    auth = ('admin', 'myAdminPassword')

    response = requests.post(ejabberd_api_url, headers=headers, json=data, auth=auth)
    if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Account created successfully")
else:
    print("Failed to create account:", response.text)
```

I am getting a code 10 response from the server saying "you are not authorized to call this command.
here is a copy of my ejabberd.yml file:

```
hosts:
  - example.com

loglevel: info

certfiles:
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5223
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    tls: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
    shaper: s2s_shaper
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme
  -
    port: 3478
    ip: "::"
    transport: udp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true

  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128

  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@example.com"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
   pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
      - mod_http_api
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - register
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal:
    rate: 3000
    burst_size: 20000
  fast: 100000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    docroot: "/opt/uploads"
    put_url: "https://example.com:5443/upload"
    get_url: "https://example.com:5443/upload"
    file_mode: "0644" # File permissions
    max_size: 10485760 # Max upload size in bytes (10 MB)
    thumbnail: false # set to true to generate thumbnails
    custom_headers:
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://@HOST@"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  #mod_offline: 
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
  
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ip_access: all
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_stun_disco: {}
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

I have been trying to add the new user using my admin credentials for now but ideally I would prefer to have a user say 'apiuser' who would be allowed to create accounts only from one ip address.Although I'll be happy if someone could show my what wrong with my .yml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple problem in your python script, once solved the feature should work. I'll also  comment other improvements you can make.

You are providing only the account username:

```py
  auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin", "myAdminPassword"))
```

you should provide the account JID, including the hostname:

```py
  auth=HTTPBasicAuth("admin@localhost", "myAdminPassword"))
```

---

There is a line with a problematic additional blankspace in your configuration, I guess the problem is only in your copy&paste. There is a problematic blankspace in the `pubsub_createnode` line:

```yaml
  muc_create:
    allow: local
   pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
```

---

If your registration script will run in a machine with a specific IP address, you can specify it in your configuration script. For example, I run the script in localhost, which may be the IPv4 `127.0.0.1` address or the IPv6 `::1` address. Also, I only grant permission to run the `register` and `unregister` commands.

```yaml
api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "register script":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          user: admin@localhost
          ip: 127.0.0.1/8
      access:
        allow:
          user: admin@localhost
          ip: "::1"
    what:
      - register
      - unregister
    from:
      - mod_http_api
```

---

If you want to grant this permission to another account, simply specify that one:

```yaml
user: apiuser@localhost
```

---

You opened the port to spam registration:

```yaml
  mod_register:
    ip_access: all
```

That is not needed at all. In fact, if the accounts on your server will be registered using only your script, you can disable registration in mod_register (which implements In-Band Registration):

```yaml
  mod_register:
    access: none
```

---

And just for reference, I used this example python script for my testing:

```py
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "https://localhost:5443/api/register"
data = {
    "user": "username2",
    "host": "localhost",
    "password": "password"
}

res = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("apiuser@localhost", "myApiuserPassword"))

print(res)
```